# How to change and check which Typescript version is used as target version

Tags: typescript

Having typescript code in a file called `main.ts` to compile it using ES5, for example, we use:
`tsc -t ES5 main.ts`

How to set ES5 (or other version as default target version globally)? I know we can add this to a configuration file, but it will be local.

Also, how to check what is the current target version used on a machine? I was reading that ES3 is the default, but if we change the default, how we check what became the current default on that machine?

Comment: You could inherit the config from a global file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `tsconfig.json`
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html.
There you can set serval compile options.
For example:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true
   }
```